# How to loop over my inventory list in jinja2 (currently using a template in my playbook)

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I'm attempting to get the output of some show commands on some network devices. My current code loops over the same host 4 times instead of over all 4 hosts in my inventory file. How do I rectify this ?

Using Ubuntu 16.04 server, Ansible 2.7

```
My Jinja template:
{% for host in groups.ios_devices %}
 {% if not host==inventory_hostname %}
.......
hostname: {{device_info.ansible_facts['ansible_net_hostname']}}
Interfaces: {{int_status}}
.......
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
## ios_devices is my host inventory file with all ip-addresses##

Playbook:
----------
 template:
       src: ./template/temp.j2
       dest: report.txt
```

I expected this to run across all my inventory host ip's , but see that the output has loops over the same ip.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to  happen here: while your `host` variable is looping over the values in `groups.ios_devices`, you're not using that value in any of your variable lookups, so of course you're always going to see the same information on each loop iteration. You're always asking for the same variables.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use '*hostvars*'. See below

```
hostname: {{ hostvars[host].ansible_hostname }}
Interfaces: {{ hostvars[host].ansible_interfaces }}
```

"In order to do this, Ansible must have already talked to ‘*ios_devices*’ in the current play, or another play up higher in the playbook. This is the default configuration of ansible." See [Caching Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#caching-facts).

For example, starting the play like below will cache facts about hosts in the group ‘*ios_devices*’

```
- hosts: ios_devices
  gather_facts: yes
```

But, this will run the playbook and the '*template*' task at each host in the group. To avoid it the '*template*' task can be [run_once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once). See below

```
- template:
    src: ./template/temp.j2
    dest: report.txt
  run_once: true
```

But, because of the condition in the template (see below), this will exclude from '*report.txt*' the host which is the playbook run at.

```
{% if not host==inventory_hostname %}
```

Cache the facts about ‘*ios_devices*’ and run the playbook at a host which is not a member of ‘*ios_devices*’ if all members of ‘*ios_devices*’ shall be included in '*report.txt*'. See below

```
- hosts: ios_devices
  gather_facts: yes
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: ./template/temp.j2
        dest: report.txt
```

Or, remove the condition '*host==inventory_hostname*' from the template. The file '*report.txt*' will be created at the host the '*template*' task is run at, of course.

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Botka. This works great.
A bigger thank you for the detailed explanation with the concepts.